# Visual C++ WebBrowser Block popups

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using C++ to write a simple web browser.

Can you help me to block IE popups please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click WebBrowser in Windows Form design time, and open property window of WebBrowser.
2. Add NewWindow event handler at Event tab of property window.

**Then to hide popups add this codeline:**

```
   e->Cancel = true;
```